# Horizontal alignment of many elements in the same container

Tags: html, css

I have an  element on which I have a FontAwesome icon and some text, my question is, is there any possibility to horizontally align multiple elements within one container no matter what kind of elements are inside (text, icons, others). In my example text is aligned bottom and the icons are middle aligned, how can I middle align text too...

Here is a small example:
http://jsbin.com/yureyi/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Didn't you mean vertically ?

Comment: do you mean something like: [this?](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/z2qdy8Lw/) (I took the liberty to vertically align as well)

Comment: In your jsbin you aligned horizontally, not vertically...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `vertical-align` on the FontAwesome icon, like so:

```
i{font-size: 2em; vertical-align: middle;}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/lohozekiru/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<center>` tag which ususaly overrides all default aligns for "horizontal middle".

For real (vertical) middle, use div and margin. If you will set text margin from bottom as (img height - text height) / 2 then it will display in middle of image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Start your code here -->
<a href="#" id="linkfc" class="list-group-item">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check" style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;"></i>
  <div style="margin: 5px; font-size: 5px;">Dealer Code</div></a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note that if I diplay this code as separate page in FireFox it display correctly. For some reason in your sample above image appear much bigger.

Answer (score 1):

You can also vertical align elements using css translate.

For instance wrap your "dealer text" in a paragraph tag and try the following:

```
body{padding: 50px}

i{font-size: 2em;}

a p {font-size:18px;  
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

Setting the line-height property also works if you know the height of the parent element. This codepen has some great tutorials:
[Vertical alignment](http://codepen.io/sebastianekstrom/pen/kzEhe)

Answer (score 1):

Roger Johansson wrote an entire article on this matter, just choose what suits you better: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201303/how_to_shrinkwrap_and_center_elements_horizontally/

Also, I wrote about an alternative method, using `fit-content` sizing, which is a W3C working draft: https://catalin.red/horizontal-centering-using-css-fit-content-value/

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

According to your example, to make both text and icon vertical align, how about try the code as follow:

```
.icon, .text {
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  *zoom: 1;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```